How to debug Nodejs in Visual Studio?
I created a Nodejs Console Application and wanted to debug it. After setting a breakpoint, I pressed F5 but then came an error

Unable to start the program XXXXXX
The debugger is not properly installed. Cannot debug the requested type of code. Run setup to install to repair this debugger
How to debug this application?

Try a few of the following methods to fix the debugger and debug your Node.js application:
1: In Visual Studio, select Tools > Options > Debugging > General, uncheck the "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome, Edge and IE)" option, and then restart Visual Studio.
2: Check whether the Node.js debugging tool is installed correctly. Run: npm install -g node-inspect to install or update the Node.js debugging tool.
3: Reinstalling or repairing Visual Studio may help resolve the issue where the debugger is not installed correctly.

I tried all of above but none of them works

Try going to Tools > Get Tools and Features..., unchecking the Node.js development workloads to make modifications, then restarting the computer and re-checking those workloads to reinstall them. Additionally, I recommend you follow this link to reinstall the latest version of Node.js: https://nodejs.org/en/download/prebuilt-installer
